# How to install shapely via .whl when "not supported wheel on this platform"

Tags: python-3.x, shapely

all. I am trying to install shapely via the .whl using pip. I have python 3.6.13 running on anaconda prompt. I have downloaded the shapely .whl using [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) site. However, when I run the commands shown in the image below, I get the error "shapely... is not a supported wheel on this platform."

[image]

From what I understand, I have a 64 bit architecture and python 3.6 (although it is python 3.6.13). I have tried to just request python 3.6 flat from the virtual environment setup by using the following command:

```
conda create -n stormEnv python=3.6
```

However, this command always returns a python version that is higher than a flat 3.6.

I am wondering if there is a way to get a python version that is a flat 3.6, or if I am just using the wrong .whl file from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

I have also tried the 3.6 32bit architecture as shown in the next image without any success:

[image]

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working with conda, the first thing you should try is:

```
conda install shapely
```

There is likely to be an existing build for your platform available in conda forge.

Wheel files are tagged with compatibility markers, and you should not attempt to install an incompatible wheel directly, because the the compiled artifacts inside the wheel will not work on your platform. You'll have to find a wheel which is supported on your platform - to see the list of supported tags run:

```
python -m pip debug -v
```

If there are no compatible wheels available, you'll have to install the necessary build dependencies and then install directly from source code.

Comment: I used your command and got the error: "python3" is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Use `python -m pip debug -v`. I forgot that conda envs set a `python` cmd but not a `python3` cmd.